# Increment the numeric value in column D by 1 if column E is TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script below that colors column D red if column E is set to TRUE.

I'm trying to adapt the script so instead it increments the value in Col D by 1 if Col E is set top TRUE.

How can I do that?

```
 function myFunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PlayWon");
      var TF = sheet.getRange("E2:E40").getValues();
      for (i=0; i<40; i++) {
       var r = i+2;
       if (TF[i] == "true") {
         sheet.getRange(r,4).setBackground("red");
       }
    }
    }
```